# create new Exception type

Tags: c#, exception

I want to create new exception type to catch it with specify logging. But I want to pass int value to ctor. How to do it? I try :

```
public class IncorrectTimeIdException : Exception
{
    public IncorrectTimeIdException(int TypeID) : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

but I got an error during compilation.

Comment: 'message' is not defined; so, instead of base(message) try base("Something wrong")

Comment: the exception message (no pun intended) should tell you exactly what's wrong in this case

Comment: See http://blog.gurock.com/articles/creating-custom-exceptions-in-dotnet/ for a how-to for new exception types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class IncorrectTimeIdException : Exception
{
    private void DemonstrateException()
    {
        // The Exception class has three constructors:
        var ex1 = new Exception();
        var ex2 = new Exception("Some string"); // <--
        var ex3 = new Exception("Some string and  InnerException", new Exception());

        // You're using the constructor with the string parameter, hence you must give it a string.
    }

    public IncorrectTimeIdException(int TypeID) : base("Something wrong")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question. When I construct my exception, do I call a method similar to DemonstrateException or it's done naturally?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code you can use to create a custom exception class that carries some additional data (in your case the type ID) and also follows all the "rules" for creating a custom exception. You can rename the exception class and the rather non-descript custom data field to your liking.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class CustomException : Exception {

  readonly Int32 data;

  public CustomException() { }

  public CustomException(Int32 data) : base(FormatMessage(data)) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public CustomException(String message) : base(message) { }

  public CustomException(Int32 data, Exception inner)
    : base(FormatMessage(data), inner) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public CustomException(String message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }

  protected CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    : base(info, context) {
    if (info == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
    this.data = info.GetInt32("data");
  }

  public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,
    StreamingContext context) {
    if (info == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
    info.AddValue("data", this.data);
    base.GetObjectData(info, context);
  }

  public Int32 Data { get { return this.data; } }

  static String FormatMessage(Int32 data) {
    return String.Format("Custom exception with data {0}.", data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `public Int32 Data { get { return this.data; } }` actually be `public new Int32 Data { get { return this.data; } }`?  Otherwise you will get IDE warning `CS0114 - hides inherited member`.  Also, would it not be the same to change `readonly Int32 data;` to `private Int32 data;` or maybe even better?

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you exactly what the problem is - `message` isn't defined.

Try this instead which allows you to supply a user message when you create the exception:

```
public IncorrectTimeIdException(string message, int TypeID) : base(message)
{
}

// Usage:
throw new IncorrectTimeIdException("The time ID is incorrect", id);
```

Or alternatively this, which creates an exception with no message:

```
public IncorrectTimeIdException(int TypeID)
{
}
```

Or finally this, which creates an exception with a pre-defined message:

```
public IncorrectTimeIdException(int TypeID) : base("The time ID is incorrect")
{
}
```

If you like you can also declare multiple constructors on your class, so you can provide a constructor that uses a pre-defined message at the same time as providing a constructor that allows you to override that message.